# How to stop the current Youtube video, when we start a new one?

Tags: java, android, android-youtube-api

Using the Youtube API for the first time, when I start a Youtube video and when I want to launch a new one, without stopping the first one, the sound of the second video is superimposed on that of the first. The method release() is inefficient. How can I fix it?

````
public class YoutubeVideoView implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener, YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener {
    private String mUrlYoutubeVideo;
    private FragmentActivity baseActivity;
    private View view;

    public YoutubeVideoView(FragmentActivity activity) {
        this.baseActivity = activity;
    }

    public FragmentActivity getBaseActivity() {
        return baseActivity;
    }

    public void setBaseActivity(FragmentActivity baseActivity) {
        this.baseActivity = baseActivity;
    }

    public View getView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup root) {
        view = inflater.inflate(getLayoutID(), root, false);
        return view;
    }

    private int getLayoutID() {
        return R.layout.layout_youtube_video_view;
    }

    public void fillData(String url) {
        this.mUrlYoutubeVideo = url;
        YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getBaseActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.youtube_layout, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();
        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(getBaseActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.developer_key_youtube), this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {
        Utils.doLog("onInitializationSuccess");
        youTubePlayer.release();
        youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.MINIMAL);

        if (!wasRestored) {
            String youtubeVideoId = Utils.getYoutubeIdFormUrl(mUrlYoutubeVideo);
            youTubePlayer.cueVideo(youtubeVideoId);
        }
        youTubePlayer.setPlayerStateChangeListener(this);```

    }
````

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested this on an actual phone?

Android Emulator always plays sound like that. But just by doing `.loadVideo(string)` it works perfect for me.